# using jquery plugin with dynamic data comes from services in angular4

Tags: jquery, angular

i recent using angular4 and i want to make ticker the ticker's data come from ticker service in angular4
the ticker service code is

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

 @Injectable()
 export class TickerService {

  constructor() { }
    getTickerList()
    {
        return[{img:"../../assets/images/profile-pics.jpg",title:"Added New 
         Post-1",des:"كما يشترط فيها أن تحقق هدفاً أو أكثر من الأهداف 
           الخاصة بالجائزة وفق تقدير اللجنة. كان من المقرر منح أول جائزة 
    منها سنة 1399هـ / 1979م إلا أنها حُجبت لعدم توفر متطلبات الفوز بها في 
        الأعمال المرشحة تلك السنة"},
       {img:"../../assets/images/profile-pics.jpg",title:"Added New Post-
        2",des:"كما يشترط فيها أن تحقق هدفاً أو أكثر من الأهداف الخاصة 
        بالجائزة وفق تقدير اللجنة. كان من المقرر منح أول جائزة منها سنة 
        1399هـ / 1979م إلا أنها حُجبت لعدم توفر متطلبات الفوز بها في 
         الأعمال المرشحة تلك السنة"}         
      ];
     }

 }
```

and this data from service i use it in ticker component the ticker component code is

```
   import { TickerService } from './ticker.service';
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var jquery:any;
    declare var $ :any;
    declare var easyTicker : any;
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-ticker',
      templateUrl: './ticker.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./ticker.component.css'],
       providers:[TickerService]
   })
   export class TickerComponent implements OnInit {
   public tickerList;
   constructor(private service:TickerService ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   this.tickerList = this.service.getTickerList();
    //easy ticker is jquery plugin function and i selsct the class of div that will be content ticker data
    $('.ticker1').easyTicker({
        direction: 'up',
        easing: 'swing',
        speed: 'slow',
        interval: 500,
        height: '200px',
        visible: 0,
        mousePause: 1,
        controls: {
          up: '',
          down: '',
          toggle: '',
          playText: 'Play',
          stopText: 'Stop'
        }
      });


   }

  }
```

and i want to use this ticker list in ticker html to render this dynamic data and when i use jquery plugin with data it run well and there is no problem but when i render dynamic data this plugin don't run well and the ticker html

```
<!-- start of ticker -->
<div class="menu-div">
<div class="title-panel black15">
  What's going on
</div>
<!-- Start of ticker -->    
<div class="ticker1">

    <div class="ticker-menu black15 " style=" overflow-y: auto;" *ngFor= "let list of tickerList">      
                <div class="ticker-menu-item">
                    <div class="thumb-profile-img">
                        <a href="#"><img class="img-circle-50" src="{{list.img}}"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="black15">{{list.title}}</a>
                        <p class="truncation gray15">{{list.des}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
      </div>
</div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: may be you are calling jquery plugin before *ngFor finish rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to apply `easyTicker` over DOM before it is getting available inside a DOM. You could wait till that DOM gets filled in with `*ngFor` collection by using `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. `ngAfterViewInit` Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views. Apply your jQuery function inside `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. Specifically here `ngAfterViewInit` will work well in this case, since you're retrieving collection synchronously. When you're following async way you have to deal with this situation in other way.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

   $('.ticker1').easyTicker({ 
      ....
   });

};
```